# Postgres migration error - error: type already exists

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

```
exports.up = async (knex) => {
  await knex.raw(`
    ALTER TABLE accounts.login RENAME COLUMN type TO old_type;
    CREATE TYPE newest_login_type AS ENUM('hidden', 'github', 'twitter', 'google');
    ALTER TABLE accounts.login ADD COLUMN type newest_login_type;
  `);

  const types = await knex('accounts.login').select('old_type', 'user_id');

  await Promise.all(types.map(async ({ user_id, old_type }) => {
    return knex('accounts.login').where('user_id', user_id).update({ type: old_type });
  }));

  await knex.raw(`
    ALTER TABLE accounts.login DROP COLUMN old_type;
  `);
};

exports.down = async (knex) => {
  await knex.raw(`
    ALTER TYPE newest_login_type RENAME TO old_login_type;
    CREATE TYPE newest_login_type AS ENUM('hidden', 'github', 'twitter');
    ALTER TABLE accounts.login ALTER COLUMN type TYPE newest_login_type USING type::text::newest_login_type;
    DROP TYPE old_login_type;
  `);
};
```

When I `migrate` it works, then `rollback` works, then `migrate` again throws the following error:

> error: type "newest_login_type" already exists

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised how that code even can work, but your problem is that `up` script expects that `newest_login_type` doesn't exist and your down script does not remove that type, but only renames and recreate it.

So:

1. running up, `newest_login_type` is created
2. running down `newest_login_type` is modified
3. running up again fails, because `newest_login_type` already exist

ps. That shouldn't work at all because you should not pass multiple SQL statements to single `knex.raw` call. That is just not supported by many DB drivers including `pg` driver that is used with knex's postgresql dialect.

Comment: Multiple statements in a single `knex.raw` call are all over our migrations code, so it definitely works :)

Comment: Interesting. Which knex / pg versions are you using? have you set some special connection parameters for it? (I've been knex maintainer for many years and im sure that has not been always possible)

Comment: I can dig into this later to find out. I don't know off the top of my head. I fixed my problem, my `down` needed to create a type for the enum equivalent to the status quo type. Up could create the new one. Thanks Mikael

Comment: Found it :) https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1190 (works as long as parameter bindings are not used... like with mysql it can be done too)